Yet another warning: ‘<anonymous>’ may be used uninitialized
I saw many other questions about the very same warning, but my code seems different.
And, over all, I get this only with -Os option.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

template <class TYPE,class FUNC> struct AutoDestruct
    {
    const TYPE & var ;
    FUNC         func ;
    AutoDestruct ( const TYPE & v , FUNC f ) : var(v),func(f) {}
   ~AutoDestruct ()                          { func(var) ;}
    };

class Dictionary
    {
    public:
        Dictionary & wipe  () { cout << "Dictionary.wipe()\n" ; return *this ;}
    };

static void wipe_dict ( Dictionary * dict ) { dict->wipe() ;}
typedef AutoDestruct<Dictionary*,void(*)(Dictionary*)> AutoWipe ;
    
int main ()
    {
    cout << "enter main function    " << __DATE__ << "  " << __TIME__ << endl ;
    Dictionary headers ;
    AutoWipe   auto_wipe( &headers,wipe_dict ) ;
    cout << "exit main function\n" ;
    }

The command line is :
g++ -std=c++11 -Os -Wall -Wextra test.cpp && ./a.out
N.B.: If I remove the -Os option, I get no warning.
The output is :
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:48: warning: ‘<anonymous>’ may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    9 |    ~AutoDestruct ()                          { func(var) ;}
      |                                                ^~~~
test.cpp:25:46: note: ‘<anonymous>’ was declared here
   25 |     AutoWipe   auto_wipe( &headers,wipe_dict ) ;
      |                                              ^
enter main function    May 13 2024  20:14:01
exit main function
Dictionary.wipe()

and the compiler is :
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
This is a very simple extract of my real code, just to expose the warning.
But notice that in my real code, I get the warning AND a seg fault when executing the auto_wipe !
Any idea of the warning + seg fault cause ?
Thanks in advance !

Side note: In order to optimize the code, the compiler has to take a much longer, deeper look at the code. Often this results in the compiler spotting additional issues and reporting more warnings.

Thank you @user4581301, but it's not only a matter of warning, in my real code, it also crashes (but I haven't managed to reproduce the issue in a small example).

auto_wipe(&headers, wipe_dict); when you have the var reference be bound to a temporary (i.e., &headers), then access the dangling reference later on, that results in undefined behavior.  (I misinterpreted the compiler version for being Oneiric Ocelot.)

and the version (as given in my post) is 11.4.0

const TYPE& should be const TYPE - otherwise you'll have a reference to a temprary pointer as Eljay pointed out

I am not recommending that you go unoptimized to eliminate the warning or anything like that. I'm just explaining why the warning goes away without optimization.  The problem itself probably doesn't go away, and if it did could you trust it to stay away?

I see a clear violation of rule 350. You have a none-trivial, none-default destructor without proper copy constructor and assignment operator; thus in real code some sort of resource errors are expected.

Storing a reference as class member is another dark trick, used in special occasions for classes that are meant to be used as prvalue-only. This is also expected to create runtime problems. You need to avoid that one too.

Why are you bringing in the entire std:: namespace when you only use a couple items?  Have you tried something like using std::cout;?

Thanks all !
At the end of the day, I solved my issue by just removing the const & from my template AutoDestruct.
template <class TYPE,class FUNC> struct AutoDestruct
    {
    TYPE         var ;
    FUNC         func ;
    AutoDestruct ( TYPE v , FUNC f ) : var(v),func(f) {}
   ~AutoDestruct ()                          { func(var) ;}
    };

So var stores a pointer and no more a reference.
Thanks to the reverse order of the call of the destructors, I'm sure that wipe is called before the object is destructed.

I think it is worthwhile to take a small detour because I suppose I wasn't the only one who initially misread your code. The code I thought I was reading is this:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class TYPE,class FUNC> struct AutoDestruct {
    TYPE& var ;
    FUNC func ;
    AutoDestruct(TYPE& v, FUNC f ) : var(v),func(f) {}
    ~AutoDestruct () { func(var) ;}
};

struct Dictionary {
    Dictionary & wipe  () { cout << "Dictionary.wipe()\n" ; return *this ;}
};

static void wipe_dict ( Dictionary & dict ) { dict.wipe() ;}
typedef AutoDestruct<Dictionary,void(*)(Dictionary&)> AutoWipe ;
    
int main () {
    Dictionary headers ;
    AutoWipe auto_wipe( headers,wipe_dict) ;
}

auto_wipe stores a reference to headers, and when its destructor is called it calls headers.wipe();. Then headers destructor is called and all is fine.
Though in your code, here:
AutoWipe   auto_wipe( &headers,wipe_dict ) ;

Your auto_wipe stores a reference to the temporary pointer returned by &headers. When auto_wipe's destructor is called, the object headers is of course still stored at the same memory address. Nevertheless, the temporary pointer resulting from &headers is long gone and the member is a dangling reference. You can either copy the pointer, as suggested in comments, or store a reference to the actual object, as above.
TL;DR: The compiler is right to warn. You store a dangling reference. Using an address sanitizer will highlight the issue.
